# MQTT and Arduino

Tags: arduino, client, mqtt

Can I create clients acting as publishers and subscribers on Arduino using the MQTT.h library in C; use the Mosquitto broker on desktop and try establishing M2M Communication? Also, where can I get the WMQTT GUI so that I can test my clients separately (possibly a link)? Are there any GUI open source broker's available?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of MQTT client libraries available for the Arduino. If you open the library manager (`Sketch -> Include Library -> Manage Libraries...`), and search for MQTT you'll find them. I'm the maintainer of the `PubSubClient` library you'll find in that list - for more information see http://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/

[mqtt-spy](http://kamilfb.github.io/mqtt-spy/) is one open source gui tool available for interacting with topics. The `mosquitto` broker comes with `mosquitto_sub` and `mosquitto_pub` command-line tools for subscribing and publishing to a broker - they are useful for testing with.